# How to save my Arraylist into SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, hashmap

I want to save my
`ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>()` in SQLite database and later retrieve it to display the items stored in it. How can I achieve this? 
Please provide examples. 
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks ... but i don't know, in which way will this article help me??

Comment: Sorry, I thought your question was how to implement an SQLite database. My bad.

Comment: http://mrbool.com/how-to-insert-data-into-a-sqlite-database-in-android/28895

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Tutorial Link](http://mrbool.com/how-to-insert-data-into-a-sqlite-database-in-android/28895)

Please refer to the link above. I has a working example of using HashMap for SqLite operations using SQliteOpenHelper. It has one insertion at a time, but you might wanna create a loop, if you wish to insert them all in one instance.

Comment: yeah i've gone through this , will implement it to my requirements and let u know .... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize it using the default standard java serializer or us your own lib. 
Following your perf. needs: you can read this benchmark: https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki

Comment: Thanks @Fred ... i guess this might work ... if there are any other simple ways, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there more than one records in your HashMap. If so, You will save every records.
There are best way save to file as a serialized object
Save to file:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        List<Map<String, String> list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        fos = getContext().openFileOutput(OFFERS_FILE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(list);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            }
            if (oos != null) {
                oos.flush();
                oos.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Read from file:

```
List<Map<Integer, String>> orderData = null;

FileInputStream fis = null;
ObjectInputStream ois = null;
try {
fis = getContext().openFileInput(OFFERS_FILE_NAME);
ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
orderData = (HashMap<Integer, String>) ois.readObject();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace(); // We have not data in SD Card

} finally {
        try {
        if (fis != null)
            fis.close();
        if (ois != null)
            ois.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < yourlistname.size(); i++) 
                    {
                            String sql = "INSERT or replace INTO tbl_Resources (resourceID, contentID, imgpath) "

                                            + "VALUES ('"
                                            + sitesList.get(i)
                                            + "', '"
                                            + sitesList.get(i)
                                            + "', '"
//                                          
                                            +sitesList.get(i)
                                            + "')";                 
                        db.execSQL(sql);

                    }   


for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            //insert stat like by this you will get listCountry.get(i))

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

How about you itterate through that arraylist and just add it to the database...?